# JQuery pop up windows help needed

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a pop up window without using any plug-ins. So far I wrote the code which works for one element and I wonder what can I do to make it work with more than one.

I can do what I want by copy pasting the all the code with different IDs on each item. But I believe there is a better way to do so :)

Thanks in advance.

Here the code I am using:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <section id="s1" data-index="1">
        //section one content
     </section>

     <section id="s2" data-index="2">
        <div class="container">
          <img class="button" src='img1.png' alt="" />
           <img class="button" src='img2.png' alt="" />
            <img class="button" src='img3.png' alt="" />

             <img class="popUp" src='largeImage1.png' alt="" />
            <img class="popUp" src='largeImage2.png' alt="" />
           <img class="popUp" src='largeImage3.png' alt="" />
          </div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.button{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.popUp{
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index:9999;
}
.cover{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(".button").click(function () {
        $(".popUp").fadeIn(500);
        $(".cover").fadeTo(500, 0.5);
});

$(".popUp").click(function () {
        $(".popUp").fadeOut(500);
        $(".cover").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: post all the relevant html code

Comment: The way to specify 1 object is to send the ID of that specific object to the function and in that way get information needed to select the object you want to handle.

Answer (score -1):

thy this:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function(){
   var left  = ($(window).width()/2)-(900/2),
   top   = ($(window).height()/2)-(500/2),
   url = "http://google.com";
   window.open( url, "popup", "width=780, height=550, top=30, left="+left );
});
```

Comment: No, not this way. Read OPs question. And why do you declare `top` in your code and not use it?